# From collation Modern_Spanish_CI_AI (in SQL Server) to UTF-8 (in MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, encoding

I am writing a PHP script to import some data from a Microsoft SQL Server database to my MySQL database.

Collation in the SQL Server is Modern_Spanish_CI_AI (so I guess the encoding is ASCII), and in my MySQL database I'm using UTF-8 encoding and utf8_unicode_ci as collation.

When I import the data I get wrong characters corresponding to the Spanish letter Ñ. I've tried to use the PHP functions utf8_encode($string) and mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8") without any success, (I got different wrong characters but still wrong).

Perhaps this helps:
Table's definition in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable] (
[myField] varchar(2) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NOT NULL,
```

Table's definition in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
`myField` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with SQL server, but from a cursory glance at [this collation chart](http://www.collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0C0A.1252.Modern_Spanish_CI_AI.html), `Modern_Spanish_CI_AI` seems to be essentially a Windows-1252 character set, probably with some Spanish sorting / comparison rules on top.

You should be able to convert the data like this:

```
$utf8 = iconv("windows-1252", "utf-8", $input);
```

try it out. However, when using PHP for this, the character set of the connection to each database also plays a role - if it still doesn't work, you need to show some more code.